# SVSegmentedControlをStoryboardで使いたい

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, cocoapods

UIControlをカスタムしたSVSegmentedControlですが、こちらをStoryborad上でサイズなどを調整して使いたいのですが、方法がみつかりません。
以下にSVSegmentedControlのリンクを記します。
https://github.com/samvermette/SVSegmentedControl

普通は項目の配列を決め、インスタンス化します。

```
SVSegmentedControl *navSC = [[SVSegmentedControl alloc] initWithSectionTitles:@[@"First", @"Second", @"Third"]];
```

Answer (score -1):

`IBDesignable`、`IBInspectable`を利用すると、すこしはマシかもしれません。

[@IBDesignableと@IBInspectableを使ってグラデーション可能なカスタムViewを作ってみた](http://qiita.com/mo_to_44/items/762f42c22ae70c689cb9)

Objective-Cでは、`@`をつけずに記述します。IBOutlet、IBActionと同様です。
IBDesignableは、drawRectメソッド内で、静的な描画を行っている場合に限り、Storyboard上で、描画が反映されます。